# ElasticSearch - How to sort by "date_range"

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to sort by "date_range" field in Elasticsearch?
If yes, how?

My Elasticsearch version: 6.3.0

You can find my examples below.

I want to sort by "dater"

Thanks,

Mapping:

```
PUT testindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "datetest": {
      "properties": {
        "created": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "Name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "dater": {
                    "type": "date_range"
                }      
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

query:

```
GET /testindex/_search
{
 "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "dater": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

result:

```
error": {
        "root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Fielddata is not supported on field [dater] of type [date_range]"
          }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Sorting need a scalar value for comparison between two documents. What do you mean by sorting on a range? Do you want to sort on the lower bound? Sort by the time window length?

Comment: I want to sort by lower bound. In my case - "dater.gte"

Comment: and did you try "sort": [
    {
      "dater.gte": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ] ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but no success. {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "No mapping found for [dater.gte] in order to sort on",
        "index_uuid": "Q-OcBkfWSyeTfRzow1M0qQ",
        "index": "testindex"
      }

Comment: then you cant =) So you need to index your range start date as another field in your document with a type date.